# Why are these two definitions of a connection equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I'm working through Kai Köhler's "Differentialgeometrie und homogene Räume" (Differential geometry and homogenous spaces) and struggle to understand the notion of a connection on a vector bundle. In particular, I do not completely understand why two definitions are equivalent. The main definition that the author gives is the following:

> Let $ E \to M$ be a vector bundle. A (covariant) connection $\nabla$ on $E$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\nabla:\Gamma(M,E)\to \Gamma(M,T^*M \otimes E)$, that satisfies Leibniz's rule: $\forall f\in C^\infty(M),s\in \Gamma(M,E): \nabla(f\cdot s) = df \otimes s + f\nabla s$.

Apparently, it is equivalent to ask for $\nabla$ to be a map $\nabla:\Gamma(M,TM) \times \Gamma(M,E) \to \Gamma(M,E)$, that is $C^{\infty}$-linear in the first and satisfies the Leibniz rule in the second argument. Why does this hold? Also, what is a good intuition to think about $df \otimes s$ ?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114283/two-definitions-of-a-connection).

Answer (score 2):

Let $X \in \Gamma(M, TM)$ and $s \in \Gamma(M, E)$.

If $\nabla$ is a connection according to the first definition, then we can produce $D$, a connection according to the second condition, by defining $D(X, s) := (\nabla s)(X)$ which is usually denoted $\nabla_Xs$.

Conversely, if $D$ is a connection according to the second definition, then we can produce $\nabla$, a connection according to the first condition, by defining $\nabla s := D(\cdot, s)$.

---

As for $df\otimes s$, note that $df \in \Gamma(M, T^*M)$ and $s \in \Gamma(M, E)$, so $df\otimes s \in \Gamma(M, T^*M\otimes E)$. Given a vector field $X \in \Gamma(M, TM)$, then $(df\otimes s)(X) = df(X)\otimes s = X(f)\otimes s = X(f)s$.

Comment: But given $\nabla$ according to definition 1, how can we show $C^{\infty}$-linearity of $\nabla(s)$ or equivalently $\nabla(s)\in$Hom$(E,T^*M \otimes E)$?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Note that $\nabla s \in \Gamma(M, T^*M\otimes E)$ not $\operatorname{Hom}(E, T^*M\otimes E)$. Also, $\nabla$ is not $C^{\infty}$-linear as $\nabla(fs) \neq f\nabla s$ in general.

Comment: There is a lemma in my book saying that for another bundle $F\to M$ we have that $P:\Gamma(M,E)\to \Gamma(M,F)$ $C^{\infty}$-linear $\Leftrightarrow P\in\Gamma(M,$Hom$(E,F))$. So I think one can consider it also as a map $\nabla(s)\in \Gamma(M,$Hom$(E, T^*M \otimes E))$ if pointwise it gives a linear map between fibres.

Comment: $\nabla$ is a map $\Gamma(M, E) \to \Gamma(M, T^*M\otimes E)$, not $\nabla s$. However, $\nabla$ is not $C^{\infty}$-linear, so $\nabla \not\in \Gamma(M, \operatorname{Hom}(E, T^*M\otimes E))$.

Comment: On the other hand, fixing $s \in \Gamma(M, E)$, the map $\nabla s : \Gamma(M, TM) \to \Gamma(M, E)$ is $C^{\infty}$-linear, so $\nabla s \in \Gamma(M, \operatorname{Hom}(TM, E))$.

Comment: I wonder why $\nabla s := D(\cdot, s)$ is well-defined. What do you put for the poistion at $\cdot$? Also $D(\cdot, s)\in \Gamma(M,E)$ while $\nabla s$ is supposed to be in $\Gamma(M,T^*M\otimes E)$. Do you just define $\nabla(s) := \sum_{i=1}^n dx^i \otimes D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} s.$ with a local coordinate $x_1,...,x_n$?

Comment: @Danny: Note that $D: \Gamma(M,TM) \times \Gamma(M,E) \to \Gamma(M,E)$, so for $s \in \Gamma(M, E)$, we have $D(\cdot, s) : \Gamma(M, TM) \to \Gamma(M, E)$. Therefore, given a vector field $X \in \Gamma(M, TM)$, we obtain the section $D(X, s) \in \Gamma(M, E)$.